# Operating system error code 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)

Tags: jmeter

I am not able to analyse the error I mentioned in my title.
It's error code 32 and I am not understanding what is using the file.

I tried giving local `C:/Results/TestResult1.csv` path also but error is not solved.

> "\Server Name\C$\Users\Desktop\ONS_Results\TestResult1.csv" could not
>   be opened. Operating system error code 32(The process cannot access
>   the file because it is being used by another process.).

Comment: Check if any other application is using the file, Like its open in notepad or excel. The error message is self explanatory.

Comment: Well i tried once again the file was not open. According to me i think while JMeter writes the results to csv file that moment itself is trying to open and push the results to DB.